# MSSQL: ROW_NUMBER() in Sub-Queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This below was originally written for MySQL, with the @rownumber is defined as a scalar-variable.

```
SELECT CONCAT( z.expected, IF(z.got-1>z.expected, CONCAT(' thru ',z.got-1), '') AS `Missing Receipt ID`
FROM (SELECT @rownum \\:= @rownum+1 AS expected,
IF(@rownum=recpt_id, 0, @rownum \\:= recpt_id) AS got
FROM 
(SELECT @rownum \\:= (SELECT MIN(CAST(recpt_id AS SIGNED))-1 FROM report_receipt
WHERE outlet_desc IN "+Branch+" )
) AS a
JOIN report_receipt r
ON r.outlet_desc IN "+Branch+"
ORDER BY CAST(recpt_id AS SIGNED)
) AS z
WHERE z.got!=0
```

I am trying to create the same query but for the SQL Server platform. I am aware that in MSSQL, we can use the ROW_NUMBER function and then have a OVER(ORDER ) clause at a place where the ROW_NUMBER is called. The query is also going to be used in native query format in our Java code.

So far, after some minor syntax adjustments, I have reached to this current state in MSSQL but with some uncertainties:

```
SELECT CONCAT( z.expected, CASE WHEN z.got-1>z.expected THEN  CONCAT(' thru ',z.got-1) ELSE  '' END) AS [Missing Receipt ID]
FROM 
   (SELECT @rownum \:= @rownum+1 AS expected,
    IF(@rownum=recpt_id, 0, @rownum \:= recpt_id) AS got
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(recpt_id AS INT))) \:= (SELECT MIN(CAST(recpt_id AS INT))-1 FROM report_receipt
          WHERE outlet_desc IN "+Branch+" )
    ) AS a
JOIN report_receipt r 
ON r.outlet_desc IN ('MY011')) AS z
WHERE z.got!=0
```

What I'm unsure but looking for answers would be:

1. If there's is only one place ORDER clause is placed, do we just place it inside the innermost query while for other places we have to use only ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SELECT NULL)?
2. If the query is considered having unnecessary additional nesting, what is the other alternative without having to call too many ROW_NUMBER functions repeatedly?

Thanks in advance.

Note: The '\' is an escape character added for the Java code.